# Can "any" be used in non-negated statements such as "There is any + N"?

Tags: grammar, determiners, some-any

This may be weird to ask, but seldomly I hear people come up with these statements:

- There is any problem
- This additional wheel would cause any problem

Is this grammatically wrong?

In these situations I understand it as "There is not any problem" and "This additional wheel would not cause any problem"

It might be that I misheard the "n't" but I am not sure the reason why I miss this particular sound.

Comment: You probly missed an _if_ at the beginning of the phrase, or maybe the speaker was carrying a negative field over from a previous sentence. The reason it sounds weird qs it stands is that _any_ is a negative polarity item, which means it's ungrammatical outside a negative context. Put a negative (_I don't think_) or an _if_ in front of them and they're normal; remove the field and they go limp. [Negation is very complex.](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf)

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, there is a context in front of them that suggest the these sentences are negative. So as you say, this may still grammatically correct?

Comment: No, not as it is. The context must be in the quote or it produces garbage. That's the problem with 50% of the questions we get here -- people think the rules are just about stringing words together, and they present the part they don't understand, so we don't either. It's like cutting off your hand and mailing it to the doctor to get a bandaid on a cut.

Comment: "There is any problem" is agrammatical in English. What one would expect tp hear is: There is **some** problem. Is there **any** or **some** problem? The additional wheel may cause some problem. Would the additional wheel cause any or some problem? As a determiner, any is negative or interrogative, not declarative **unless it refers to an unrestricted something**. Any person caught stealing will be prosecuted.

Answer (score 1):

- <s>There is any problem</s> **wrong**
- There isn't any problem **correct**
- Is there any problem? **correct**

So when you think you heard sentence #1, you are right that you probably missed the `n't`. When people speak fast, it is possible that they barely pronounce the `n't`, but you should hear a longer pause after `is`, or a soft 'uh' or 'n' sound: There 'isuh' any problem / There 'isn' any problem.

Comment: This is incorrect. `problem` is a singular countable noun, it shouldn't be used with `any`.

Comment: @Alexis Any English scholar would say that that is incorrect.  And  WeWantAnyCar.com. claim: 'We will buy any car or van at [WeWantAnyCar.com](https://www.wewantanycar.com/buy-any-car).' And many sellers offer the encouraging 'If there is any problem let us know.'

Comment: Yes, there isn't any problem OR There aren't any problems. The speech thing is well expressed.

Comment: We are in `English language & Usage` if your answer isn't grammatically correct, your answer is wrong. If it's wrong but we can still hear it due to the usage or dialect or culture, you need to mention it otherwise people might think it's correct.